How to center this on iOS?
Screenshot
Hi, I have a problem with centering an element on Apple devices. In screens you can see what is happening on iOS and what is happening on Android and on a classic Windows PC. I have tried every possible method, nothing helps. Do you see a problem in my code? Any suggestions? Thank you very much for help.
Edit. The image in the center of this circle was rounded in Photoshop. I didn't use any code in this case. I only care about the issue of centering. Everything works fine on Android and PC, I assume that I'm missing some lines created specifically for iOS. Centering also doesn't work on Google Chrome for iOS.
Code:
<style>
#rotatingText {
  animation-name: rotate-circle;
  animation-duration: 22s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

u/keyframes rotate-circle {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

 .text {
      font-weight: 300;
      letter-spacing: 3.3px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Outfit';
      font-size: 14px;
      fill: white;
      text-shadow: white 1px 0 10px;;
    }

    .main {
      display: grid;
      align-items: center;
      justify-items: center;
    }
  
     .main img {
      position: absolute;
    }

    .main img {
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 500px;
      z-index: 0;
      box-shadow: rgba(245, 72, 243, 0.3) 1px 0 50px;;
    }
    
</style>

  <a target=”_blank” href="https://9ypjmq3pbhg.typeform.com/to/vz0yqohg">
  <div class="main">
<img class="img1" src="https://polygonstudio.eu/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/imgrotate2.png" width="120" height="50">

<svg id="rotatingText" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
  <defs>
    <path id="circle" d="M 100, 100
            m -75, 0
            a 75, 75 0 1, 0 150, 0
            a 75, 75 0 1, 0 -150, 0
            ">
    </path>
  </defs>
  <text width="400">
    <textPath alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#circle" class="text">
      Wypełnij formularz - wypełnij formularz -
    </textPath>
  </text>
</svg>
  </div>
  </a>

I've tried writing CSS in many different ways. I tried to look for a solution on the Internet.

I think your .main styles should be:
.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}



#rotatingText {
  animation-name: rotate-circle;
  animation-duration: 22s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate-circle {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.text {
  font-weight: 300;
  letter-spacing: 3.3px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Outfit';
  font-size: 14px;
  fill: white;
  text-shadow: white 1px 0 10px;;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
  
.main img {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 500px;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(245, 72, 243, 0.3) 1px 0 50px;
}
<a target="_blank" href="https://9ypjmq3pbhg.typeform.com/to/vz0yqohg">
  <div class="main">
    <img class="img1" src="https://polygonstudio.eu/wp-content/uploads/2024/06/imgrotate2.png" width="200" height="200">
    <svg id="rotatingText" viewBox="0 0 200 200" width="200" height="200">
      <defs>
        <path id="circle" d="M 100, 100
        m -75, 0
        a 75, 75 0 1, 0 150, 0
        a 75, 75 0 1, 0 -150, 0
        ">
        </path>
      </defs>
      <text width="400">
        <textPath alignment-baseline="top" xlink:href="#circle" class="text">
        Wypełnij formularz - wypełnij formularz -
        </textPath>
      </text>
    </svg>
  </div>
</a>



